# google map is not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to insert a Google map into a modal. The modal shows up with the shape of the map present but it's all over gray. I've searched and found suggestions such as calling the map's resize event, or setting the max-width of the map image to none, but none of these suggestions have helped so far.please help me.

javascript

```
var map;        
            var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter
});

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom: 14,
      draggable: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
  marker.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

  }); 
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap());

$('#myMapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
   //Must wait until the render of the modal appear, thats why we use the resizeMap and NOT resizingMap!! ;-)
   resizeMap();
})

function resizeMap() {
   if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
   setTimeout( function(){resizingMap();} , 400);
}

function resizingMap() {
   if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
   var center = map.getCenter();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
   map.setCenter(center); 
}
```

html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myMapModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="map-canvas" class=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
```

css

```
#map-canvas  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#map-canvas {
  width:500px;
  height:480px;
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors logged in the console?

Comment: no, there is no logged errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the model the map div is not visible at startup and the is not created porperly .. i suggest you of recall the initialize function in resizeMap on resizenMap function

```
function resizeMap() {
  initialize()
  if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
  setTimeout( function(){resizingMap();} , 400);
}

function resizingMap() {
  initialize()
  if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center); 
}
```

and anyway you must "initialize" the map when you open  the modal .. the div containing the map must be visible when the map is created ..

Comment: thanks, you saved my day :D post a real comment so I can approve it ;)

Comment: Ok i update the answer with this last suggestion in a minute